# only one array is showing using foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I use to merge two arrays in foreach loop ,first array is working fine but 2nd array shows one result and die .i hope you understand my question.

```
$output = [];
foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle) {
    $center_lat = $lat;
    $center_lng = $lon;
    $lat=$vehicle->lat;
    $lng=$vehicle->lon;

    $vehicle->distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 6371);
    $id= $vehicle->abc_id;
    $abc=DB::table('tbl')->where('id',$id)->get();

    $output [$key] = $vehicle;
    $result = array_merge($output,(array)$abc);
}

return response()->json($result);
```

why $abc is returning only one array

dd($output, $abc) shows

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#346
    +"id": 1
    +"vehicle_type": "bus"
   ...........
  }
  1 => {#100
    +"id": 3
    +"vehicle_type": "car"
    .....
  }
]
Collection {#356
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => {#352
      +"id": 3
    ........
    
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share a dd($output, $abc) please.

Comment: check updated code

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$result[] = array_merge((array)$vehicle,(array)$abc);
```

this will add `$output[$key]` and `(array)$abc` together in the same key in `$result` array

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: why this error showing "array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array"

Comment: because $vehicle is not an array it's and object you can do (array)$vechicle $result[] = array_merge((array)$vechicle,(array)$abc);

Comment: ok if i want to add more array just use comma and (array)$array3 ?

Comment: Yes you can merge many arrays as you wish separate them by comma, you can refer to PHP manual for array_merge https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are attempting to array_merge a collection.

array_merge will accept:

```
array_merge([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
// result -> [1,2,3,"a","b","c"]
```

However it does not understand how to merge objects, and a collection IS an object. eg)

```
array_merge([1,2,3], collect(['a', 'b', 'c']))
// Result: 'array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given...'
```

Also, simply type casting the collection to an array, is not going to produce results you want:

```
array_merge([4,5,6],(array) collect([1,2,3]))
// Result: [0 => 4, 1 => 5, 2 => 6, "\0*\0items" => [1,2,3]]
```

If you want to keep your code you can use:

```
    $result = array_merge($output,$abc->toArray());
```